# Hide or remove child elements and characters by CSS stylesheet

Tags: javascript, html, css, hide

I'm just having difficulty here figuring out how to hide child elements via CSS. I know it's easy doing by JS, but the Zendesk widget script is not allowing that. Well here's the code I have right now:

```
let style = document.createElement('style');
   style.innerHTML = `
    .eRhaXm {
      text-align: center !important;
      margin-left: 0px !important;
      font-size: 0px !important;
    },
  `;
parent.document.getElementById('webWidget').contentWindow.document.head.appendChild(style);
```

BTW, the current style is on the iframe. And here is the element I want to hide:

```
<div aria-hidden="true" class="styles__Name-sc-1dpp62d-1 eRhaXm">
    <span>Kopi Help</span> &nbsp; · &nbsp;
    <span>Bot</span>
</div>
```

I want to get rid of that `&nbsp; . &nbsp;` and the `<span>` element Bot. So it will only just remain:

```
<div aria-hidden="true" class="styles__Name-sc-1dpp62d-1 eRhaXm">
    <span>Kopi Help</span>
</div>
```

Comment: You can access `document` from your script to add a `<style>` element. Are you sure you cannot access existing elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `<span>` you want to address does not have any class name, you will need to [style elements based on the DOM structure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type). This might be problematic, because then your script is sensible to any change.

You also can use [Descendent combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator) to address children of an element, or the more specific [Child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator)

```css
.eRhaXm span:nth-of-type(2) { display: none; }
```

Unfortunately, text nodes are not visible to CSS. But, since it is text, you can hide it differently, for example by setting font-size to 0, which you already did.

```
.eRhaXm { font-size: 0 }
.eRhaXm * { font-size: 1rem }
```

After all, all this is quite hacky and will break once the source DOM changes.

Also, it has accessibility issues, for example the `aria-hidden` attribute is completely hiding this name element from assistive technologies.

```css
.eRhaXm {
      text-align: center !important;
      margin-left: 0px !important;
      font-size: 0px !important;
    }
    
.eRhaXm * { font-size: 1rem }
.eRhaXm span:nth-of-type(2) { display: none }
```

```html
<div aria-hidden="true" class="styles__Name-sc-1dpp62d-1 eRhaXm">
<span>Kopi Help</span> &nbsp; · &nbsp;
<span>Bot</span>
</div>
```